# How to remove read only default profile in konsole terminal in kubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, kde

Since my upgrade from Kubuntu 20 LTS to 22 LTS, a new "Default read only profile" menu item has appeared in the profiles list of the Konsole terminal. I have set up several other profiles and would like to remove this default kind of built-in profile. Is there any way to do it ?
Thanks.